# Изменить локализацию приложения при смене языка в телефоне Android

Tags: android, локализация

Есть ли способ обновить текущий layout при сворачивании приложения, смены языка в телефоне и последующем его разворачивании?

Сейчас у меня обновляются только те части интерфейса, которые зависят от данных, на которые подписываюсь, и не удивительно, там достаточно много сетитс заново, но статические части разметки, например заголовки тулбаров или какой нибудь статичный текст в текст вьб остается без изменений.

Есть вариант для каждого экрана сетить эти значения в коде, в onResume например, но экранов много, хотелось бы что то более автоматическое.

Пытался делать recreate для Activity, потом понял, что это е принесёт плода, потому что все экраны реализованы на фрагментах и пересооздавая активити ффактически ничего не добиваешься.

Нашёл такое решение (ниже), фактически оно работает, но не для текущего экрана

```
@file:JvmName("LocaleManager")

package com.healbe.healbegobe.presentation.tools

import android.annotation.TargetApi
import android.content.Context
import android.os.Build
import android.os.LocaleList
import java.util.*

fun onAttach(context: Context): Context {
    return setLocale(context, Locale.getDefault().language)
}

fun onAttach(context: Context, defaultLanguage: String): Context {
    return setLocale(context, defaultLanguage)
}

fun setLocale(context: Context, language: String?): Context {
    return if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        updateResources(context, language)
    } else updateResourcesLegacy(context, language)

}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
private fun updateResources(context: Context, language: String?): Context {
    val locale = Locale(language)
    val localeList = LocaleList(locale)
    LocaleList.setDefault(localeList)

    val configuration = context.resources.configuration
    configuration.locales = localeList

    return context.createConfigurationContext(configuration)
}

private fun updateResourcesLegacy(context: Context, language: String?): Context {
    val locale = Locale(language)
    Locale.setDefault(locale)

    val resources = context.resources

    val configuration = resources.configuration
    configuration.locale = locale
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
        configuration.setLayoutDirection(locale)
    }

    resources.updateConfiguration(configuration, resources.displayMetrics)

    return context
}
```

Нужен способ обновить локализацию приложения, не перезапуская его

Comment: Странно, что текст в тулбаре не меняется. По идее должен. По идее после смены языка активити должна пересоздаться и всё должно быть как вам надо. Может у вас хардкод строк в разметке вместо использоания ресурсов?

Comment: Точно нет. Сейчас нашёл способ пересоздавать текущие фрагмент и активити в onConfigurationChanged, но это работает только для верхушки стека